# Regex: match first slash in url -- thats it!! ? not working for some reason?

Tags: regex

Im sorry for such a stupid question! I've worked with regex patterns before but for some reason Im having trouble with this one. Matching just the first slash or wutever in a string:

```
www.blabla.com/hello/apple/apple/banana/
```

i tried this: `/?`  but it doesnt work! it still matches the other slashes!

even `ap?` matches both ap's from the apple words

wut am i doing wrong here?? its like the `?` does nothing to help the situation.
Im using http://regexpal.com/ to test this all

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i need it for a powershell script im writing

Comment: What output are you expecting ?

Comment: i want to just match the first slash. then i want to replace that first slash with some string, but thats later, i know how to replace. i first need the regex pattern that will match that first slash. seems so simple, i cant believe how frustrating this is turning out to be

Comment: assuming you want to replace a / for a |. You could use to capturing parentheses . The first one will store the part you want to keep (up to the first slash but not including it) and the second will contain just the slash. The just do your replacement like this (perl example). `s/^([^\/]*)(\/)/$1|/`.

Comment: Please see my solution using powershell.

Comment: Possibly I don't understand your question can you please give examples of what you expect? (in www.blabalc.com/hello you want to match just the first `/` and if not found to get the whole string?)

Answer (score 6):

**You can try this regex.**

```
^[^/]*/
```

Here is how to do it in **Powershell**.

```
PS C:\Users\Someone>new-variable -name address -visibility public -value "www.blabla.com/hello/apple/apple/banana/"

PS C:\Users\Someone>$address -match "^([^/]*)(/)"    

PS C:\Users\Someone>($a, $b) = $matches[1], $matches[2] #save the previously matched group in other variable to protect them from being overwritten.
#$a has 'www.blabla.com'
#$b has '/'

PS C:\Users\Someone>$address -replace "$a$b", "$a-" 
#address now has 'www.blabla.com-hello/apple/apple/banana/' 
#                               ^see the change here.
```

Comment: Why the second pair of `[]`?

Comment: did u test it in regexpal.com ? it matches everything up till and including the first slash. i need it to match JUST the slash, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: please edi_allen, can u first test your regex pattern in something like regexpal.com before posting? /^[^/]*\// doesnt match anything

Comment: It matches from the start of the line up to the first forward slash. Don't include the first and last forward slash when trying and regexpal.com. They are intended as delimiter in some languages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Powershell, which uses .NET regular expressions, try:

```
(?<!.*/.*)/
```

This is simply a negative lookbehind that checks the string prior to the match for any `/` characters followed by a match on the `/` character.  For the first `/`, there won't be any prior `/`s so the match will succeed, but for the subsequent `/`s, there will be one or more `/`s, so the lookbehind ensures that those matches will fail.

Since this is a .NET regex, I used a .NET online tester: http://regexstorm.net/tester.  There are others that should work just as well, it's just a matter of preference.  **Don't use http://regexpal.com/**, since that uses JavaScript, which doesn't work the same way as .NET regular expressions, and won't recognize negative lookbehinds.